# What keyword will help me search for music player app that plays by folders?

Tags: music-player

I used to own a galaxy s3, and the default music player had that feature. Then I upgrade to a nexus 5, and it seems like it's missing it.

I'm huge fan of organizing my music by folders on my phone's hard drive, so I need an app that can do that, or figure out how google music app does it.

How can I search for these kinds of apps?

Comment: @Izzy thanks, question rephrased. Feel free to reiterate your comment as an answer.

Comment: Brilliant re-phrasing – hats off! Promptly posted my answer, as requested :) Now going to revoke my close vote (find me ashamed ;) Good hunting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good keyword combination is already given by your question: a music player which should play folder-wise should be found using the keywords "folder play", "[folder player](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=folder%20player)", and similar combinations. In fact, there are even some players named exactly such, e.g. [Music Folder Player](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Music-Folder-Player-Free/de.zorillasoft.musicfolderplayer), [Folder Player](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Folder-Player/com.folderplayer), and many more.